# CSS issue: Why is sidebar not clickable?

Tags: css, wordpress

http://speedsociety.com/

If you take a look at my site, the instagram widgets down the left sidebar are all not clickable (after the first one)... Is it that the content_wrapper div is blocking it? I've played around for a while in firebug and cannot seem to remedy this..

Comment: `div#content_wrapper` is covering them. This isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow. If you can't ask your question without linking off-site, it doesn't belong here. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to serve as a reference for future users. This question is going to be useless as soon as you fix your site.

Comment: Err, meant to close as "too localized", not "off topic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your current issue, update your css for `sidebar_left`:

```
.sidebar_left {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative; // added
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 1; // added
}
```

This will bring up the left column, this making it available to click.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, your content_wrapper is the problem, and it has a negative margin-left. I'm still trying to understand why it's done that way... oh well, Zuul was faster then me. His advice will surelly do the trick and if that's fine for you, so, it's fine! But I'm sure you can better organize your html/css in a way that you won't even need to use z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div.content_wrapper` is blocking it.
You will have to set a higher `z-index` to make it goes on top of it. ;)

[image]